# What is the quickest way to get the String contents of a URL using Cocoa/iPhoneSDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, url, networking

Say I want to get the HTML of

```
http://www.google.com
```

as a String using some built-in classes of the Cocoa Touch framework.

What is the least amount of code I need to write?

I've gotten this far, but can't figure out how to progress. There must be an easier way.

```
CFHTTPMessageRef req;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
req = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                 CFSTR("GET"),
                                 (CFURLRef)url,
                                 kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *quickest* way is to use NSString's `+stringWithContentsOfURL:` method. However, this is a modal call, and your application will be non-responsive while it runs. You can either move it to a background thread, or use the NSURLConnection class to make a proper, asynchronous request.

Comment: It's worth noting that on the iPhone OS, the synchronous URL loading methods leak memory.

Comment: Are you referring to NSURLConnection? Where are you seeing a leak?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is as follows, however as **Ben Gottlieb** points out, this is a synchronouseRequest and will cause your program's execution to wait on the return of this function call, possibly making your application non-responsive.

```
NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]; 
NSURLRequest *req = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval:30.0 ];
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *res;
NSData *d = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                   returningResponse:&res
                                               error:&err ];
```

You can find information on writing the proper delegate methods to handle a Asynchronous Connection [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-170129) on the Apple dev-docs.