# iOS - Show imagens from URL with different sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image

I need to show in grid or list view images for from URL, equals a Gallery from pictures.

But the problem is of the image sizes, when I use from samples projects of  with images from URL from the sample project show perfectly, but when I changed the URL with different sizes don't showing more.

I don't need download the image in the device, just show(if it is possible).

1 - How I can get the image and change the size of images to show in ImageView on List or Grid View?

2 - This actions(re-size 50(+-) images + show in List images) how can be the performance of this?

Ps: I have the same project in Android platform and show perfectly.

The my main problem is because I begging with iOS now, than I need any post, tutorial... this can help me...

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider the person trying to answer you.  How can they help without seeing the code and maybe an image of the app not working?

Comment: You can also post some of your code, to get a more insightful answer

Comment: Thanks Raúl and danh,

Comment: Thanks Raúl and danh, the main problem is because I begging work with iOS now, and I haven't code, just samples that I have test. My main question is the 1 and 2 from post. If is possible then I go to studies more. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking here is a bit too vague and broad to answer all at once. Instead, it would be worthwhile to break this down into smaller tasks.

- Do you know how to download a url (which presumably contains a list of images)? (See [this SO post for an easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241860/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-get-the-string-contents-of-a-url-using-cocoa-iphones))
- Do you know how to parse the images from that url? (See [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011355/detect-url-in-nsstring).)
- Can you download the individual images? (Note that the device has to download the images to display them, even if you didn't have to do it explicitly in other code.) (See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782454/can-i-load-a-uiimage-from-a-url).)
- Have you thought about alternate ways of accomplishing this? (eg using a UIWebView)

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I receive a list of URLs from WebService, than I need get this images and show in list or grid view. Just this. And the sample code that I find here in StackOvewFlow work perfectly with the sample urls but with my not. Then I think the problem was because the different size of images. Whats can I do? Resize Images? where can I start... How I can make step 1 of the post? Thanks

Comment: @PauloKussler I've added links to other SO posts which give hints on how to complete the various steps.